# Увеличение производительности в представлении Drupal7

Tags: drupal

Имеется представление которое выводит данные с постраничной навигацией, общим объёмом ~170 тыс записей.
 Загрузка данного представления происходит очень долго около 15 секунд, но поиск среди всех этих записей, происходит весьма быстро.
Каким образом можно ускорить загрузку представления?

Comment: Ну для начала было бы неплохо ознакомиться с исходными данными, т.е. схема представления, структура таблиц + сами запросы. План выполнения тоже было бы не плохо приложить

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть в сторону кэширования представлений.

Да, и как указали в комментарии неплохо посмотреть бы на план, для этого необходимо выполнить запрос представления вне друпала.